# Keep control cables from freezing on snowblower

Tags: winter, small-engine, ice, snowblower

**Context:** I have a Husqvarna 1830HV snowblower.  The chute is controlled by steel cables a lot like bike brake cables.  They work almost exactly like bike brake cables, in fact, except for the fact that they are solid, so the cable can both push and pull, and there is no recoil spring, so the cable stays in a fixed position.

**Trouble:** It being winter, snow gets all over the machine.  When it gets above zero, the snow melts and gets into the rubber casing around the steel cable.  Then when it freezes again, the cable jams in place.

**Solution:** I don't know.  Any ideas?

Comment: I answered this, a photo of the freezing cable would help me improve my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would apply a silicone grease or silicone spray lubricant into the opening regardless of your freezing issue, this will definitely help with displacing and preventing moisture build-up. Plus, it will operate more smoothly.

To address the problem, I assume this is happening during storage?

Can you store it such that it doesn't get wet or snowed on?

If it's happening during use, then I would suggest coating the opening with a thick silicone or red rubber grease, failing that, you could cable tie some flexible plastic tubing or use heatshrink tubing to cover the area where moisture/snow is getting in.

Comment: Storage idea would be ideal... but unfortunately best option I have is a shelter, and snow blows in anyhow.  Even if it didn't, though, unless the storage was heated, the snow would still freeze in the cables.

Comment: Just use a groundsheet or some other kind of cover to keep snow off it. That combined with a rubber friendly grease and lubricant should be enough.

Comment: Think about when I'm blowing.  I get snow on the machine - in every crack and crevice (impossible to clean it all out).  A cover will keep *new snow* off, but will also make the ice spread all over the place when the temperature goes just above freezing.  (Melting, evaporation, condensation [cold machine], freezing).  A good idea, all the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure the rubber covers don't have splits in them. then use a water dispersant, WD40 is one example, in copious amounts to get any moisture out. Then re-treat as often as necessary. I had this happen with a throttle cable on a commercial van - the moisture froze and the engine could not shut down - my Dad was swearing a lot about that!!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my frozen cables by injecting antifreeze into them at the cable ends. 2 winters ago I tried this and the cables remain unfrozen in winter. The challenge is finding a location you can inject into using a fine point syringe.

Comment: No challenge - I made a container with a hole and grommet so that the complete cable end could fit into the container - add liquid and wait for it to come out the other end. Only need to remember that liquid does not flow up hill...